# ActiveRecord Transaction -- When Does the DB Commit Actually Happen?

Tags: activerecord, sidekiq

I'm having an issue with Sidekiq not finding a DB record, which I suppose is because the transaction is not fully committed before Sidekiq runs. I was under the impression that the transaction is committed inside the block:

```
User.transaction do
    # db updates here
    # commit or rollback
end

MyWorker.perform_async()
```

So is my understanding incorrect, that even after the block, the DB operations may have not been fully committed? That's the behavior I'm seeing. I've heard of `after_commit` but I'm using service objects and want to keep the logic there.

Comment: Turns out this block was a nested transaction.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewHallock, I had the exact same issue in my services. The previous comment about _nested transaction_ is what I was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your impression is correct, the transaction commits at the end of the block.  If `MyWorker` depends on the data in the block and the block commits, it should be visible when the job executes since the job is created outside of the block.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll dig into this more. I'm getting ` ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` in the worker for records which should have been saved in the transaction block.

Comment: Verify you are calling `save!` and not `save`.  A failed validation can be silently swallowed.